# Will using a temporary travel SIM affect anything on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I'm off to Japan for a couple of weeks and wanting to take my iPhone 4 as I need to contact a few people while I'm there.

If I use an international SIM to save massive roaming charges will it affect anything on my phone? i.e the apps or notes or anything else? I'll be putting my normal sim back in after 2 weeks.

Comment: Some contacts may be stored on the SIM, if it was used on a different phone perviously, but they would probably be transferred if they were important.

Answer (score 1):

**No, it shouldn't.**
Your apps and data are stored on the phone, and changing SIM card won't affect them.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp or Apps that need to be verified via a phone number would be effected but the majority of all the Apple Apps would be fine. They are all synced with your Apple ID. I would recommend only using iMessage and FaceTime with your Apple ID though so that you can’t be contacted in your temp number.